# New line using Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap Tags Input, when pressing "ENTER" it converts the test to a tag, what I want to do is combine free text with tags, so is there a way to make the "ENTER" key not convert the text to a tag?

```
<div class="bs-example">
      <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
    </div>
```

This is my input I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to switch this off via the Bootstrap API as shown [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/javascript/#data-attributes).

You'll probably need to dig into [this file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.js) to find out more.